# add content page doesnot work for other users

Tags: 7, theming

I created a few users that are responsible for adding content to the website. they are just allowed to add/remove content (defined by role). the problem is the add content link (`mywebsite/node/add`) does not display the add page, it just displays MY `page.tpl.php` . I guess `add` page is overridden by my `page.tpl.php` , how can I have admin add page for other users ?

Comment: Its displaying `page.tpl.php` of front-end theme or admin theme?

Comment: its displaying `page.tpl.php` . the only difference is user/password form is not displayed (coz it already logged in)

Comment: If possible can you update the question and add the screenshot?

Comment: the question is simple, `/node/add` page does not work for other users, it just displays `page.tpl.php`

Comment: @Mohammad, `page.tpl.php` of your custom theme? Have you checked that `print render($page['content']);` exist in your `page.tpl.php`?

Comment: by displaying page.tpl what you meaning actually? What content is displaying in this page **mywebsite/node/add** instead of showing form, and also node creation link is not **mywebsite/node/add**, link should be **mywebsite/node/add/page**. Name of Content type should be add with url. It is better if you add a screeenshot here.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola yes `page.tpl.php` of my theme. `print render($page['content']);` is not in my `page.tpl.php` . my `page.tpl.php` is set of blocks that is why I just added blocks into it

Comment: Just provide a menu link, based on the permission the node add links will be displayed. why you need to go to mywebsite/node/add

Comment: @Mohammad, you should inclue `print render($page['content']);` in your `page.tpl.php` file otherwise, it will not display content for the page.

Comment: @inizio even by doing this that menu will be linked to `mywebsite/node/add`

Comment: @ARUN, if user has access to create different content type, `node/add` will display the list of content type otherwise, it will display the `node form` of content type which user has access to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should include `print render($page['content']);` in your page.tpl.php file otherwise, it will not display content for the page.

`content` is default block which Drupal use to render content of a page.

If you do not want to use `content` region in your `theme`, then you can set `View the administration theme` permission for your user role.

Setting permission:

- Go to  `Administration -> People -> Permissions`
- Checked check-box of `View the administration theme` for your user role and save form.

Comment: where is the `View the administration theme` ?

Comment: @Mohammad, I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Mohammad, Its my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal 7 just print the following line in your page.tpl.php :

```
         <?php print $content; ?>
```

If still it does not display the content type section , then check which template file is getting called there? Track the file and print the above line.

Answer (score 0):

Node creation page URL should contain content type name at last. This means that mywebsite/node/add is wrong. If you want to create a page content then the URL should be mywebsite/node/add/page.

Generally speaking, the node creation page URL for the *nameofyourcontenttype* content type is http://yourwebsite.com/node/add/nameofyourcontenttype.

The page at node/add will only display the list of the content types for which the users can create a node.

Comment: if user has access to create different content type, node/add will display the list of content type otherwise, it will display the node form of content type which user has access to create.

Comment: @ARUN it does not even display list of content types!!! it only displays my custom `page.tpl.php` . I guess some thing is wrong with my programming. there is no region for main content of website it is just set of blocks. I wrote this `page.tpl.php` from the beginning and defined a few `DIV`s and embedded views using `views_view_embed` inside them

Comment: @Mohammad, You should include `content` region in your theme. Drupal will use this region to display main content of page.